# smooth scrolling div by div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've added this script that scroll down 100% with mouseweel at once

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.mydiv');
    var dir = 'up'; // wheel scroll direction
    var div = 0; // current div
    $(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            dir = 'down';
        } else {
            dir = 'up';
        }
        // find currently visible div :
        div = -1;
        divs.each(function(i){
            if (div<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
                div = i;
            }
        });
        if (dir == 'up' && div > 0) {
            div--;
        }
        if (dir == 'down' && div < divs.length) {
            div++;
        }
        //console.log(div, dir, divs.length);
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
        }, 200);
        return false;
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('html,body').scrollTop(divs.eq(div).offset().top);
    });
});
```

But i need to add something on it so the scrolling look smooth , how can i do that ?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JqU2T/5/)

Comment: can you please take some time out to make a fiddle -- makes it a lot easier for others to help

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/JqU2T/5/

Comment: Is the animation duration what you are after? like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JqU2T/56/. if this is not the case then try using another easing from here : http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/.

Comment: I dont really know .. 
i just want that when i scroll down div by div with that code 
i want it to be smooth because now its just like i scroll down one time and it goes very quick ... ( sorry for my bad english )

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JqU2T/57/ checkout its smooth transistion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either specify a duration for your `animate` function or an easing function to have a different animation behavior.

You can find easing functions and instruction to use theme here :

[jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

@user3127499 already provided you a working **[FIDDLE](http://www.jsfiddle.net/JqU2T/57/)**.

He changed the time to 1000 from 100

```
$('html,body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
}, 1000);
```

And added a 1000 delay here:

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(divs.eq(div).offset().top.delay(1000));
```

**There is a plugin for that:**

You will counter many other challenges while recreating the wheel, why don you you simply use this plugin named **[Scroll Section](https://github.com/guins/jQuery.scrollSections)**.

**[DEMO](http://lab.stephaneguigne.com/js/jquery-scrollsections/example/callbacks.html)**